# Java - Check if last characters in a string are numeric

Tags: java

I'd like to know what I can use to check if the last characters in a string are numeric. For example for the ID: "S000123" .

I used the following to check if it starts with E, S or X.

```
if(! id.startsWith("E") || ! id.startsWith("S") || ! id.startsWith("X")) {
    alertinputError("Incorrect format in the ID field", lineNum);
    return;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: use a regex to detect numerics. '.*\\d+'

Comment: Last how many characters do you want to check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply use `id.matches(".\\d+")`. To check if `id` starts with `E`, `S` or `X` followed by a string of digits, however, you could use

```
id.matches("[ESX]\\d+")
```

---

**Relevant Documentation**

- [`matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old post but for future readers, I thought I'll add a different approach.

I personally found regex to be very unreadable (do you know someone that can write regex without using google?)

So I prefer this approach:

```
 char lastChar = string.charAt(string.length() - 1)
 return Character.isDigit();
```

If you want to do it for the last N letters and not just 1:

```
string.substring(string.length() - n).chars()
            .allMatch(Character::isDigit);
```

Comment: You need to pass `lastChar` in to `Character.isDigit(lastChar);` while returning.

Comment: when using method reference you don't explicitly pass parameters.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-references

Answer (score 1):

A regex might work well here.

```
String foo = "bar123";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*[0-9]+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(foo);
if(m.matches)
    System.out.println("yeah!");
```

So if the string is composed of any bunch of characters followed by one or more numbers, this will print "yeah!".

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`id.matches("^.+?\\d$")`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
String id = "S000123";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ESX][0-9].*");
Matcher matcher =  pattern.matcher(id);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Answer (score 0):

All right then you can use following Code:

```
boolean flag = true;
for (int i = id.length() - 1 ; i >= id.length() - 6 ; i--)
{
   if (!Character.isDigit(id.charAt(i)))
   {
      flag = false;
      break;
   }
}
if (flag)
System.out.println("ID is valid");
else
System.out.println("ID is invalid");
```